# How can I get the link of SQL Server Express 2012 SP4 for CLI download?

Tags: sql-server-express

I need to download and install sql server express 2012 SP4 through command line.
For this to work, I would need link to complete setup file.

From somewhere, I got the link for SQL express as below:
https://download.microsoft.com/download/F/6/7/F673709C-D371-4A64-8BF9-C1DD73F60990/ENU/x64/SQLEXPRWT_x64_ENU.exe

How do I get the url for SQL Express 2012 SP4?

Comment: The "command line" is extremely vague.  Are you using PowerShell?  When you indicate you need to use a command line what do you need to use exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This](https://download.microsoft.com/download/B/D/E/BDE8FAD6-33E5-44F6-B714-348F73E602B6/SQLEXPRWT_x64_ENU.exe) is the direct download link for SQL Server 2012 SP4 Express.

From [this download page](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=56042):

> This package contains everything needed to install and configure SQL Server as a database server including the full version of SQL Server 2012 Management Studio with SP4.

(I chose the "WT" (With Tools), x64, ENU version to match what you had for SQL 2014.)

Comment: This is precisely what I have been looking for. Could you please also tell me how did you obtain this URL.
If you did it using fiddler then how

Comment: I searched for "download SQL Server 2012 SP4 Express". That led me to directly to the https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=56042 page. I then selected English and clicked the download button. I then chose the SQLEXPRWT_x64_ENU.exe file and clicked Next. I then clicked on the "click here to download manually" link. I then scrolled to the SQLEXPRWT_x64_ENU.exe line, right-clicked on the "click here to download manually" link, and chose "copy shortcut".